# Making a variable-sized surd?

Tags: symbols

Is there a get around to make `$\surd$` variable-sized via standard AMS package? For example, I would like `$\surd \frac{a}{b}$` to look like `$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$` with the elongated left line but no overline on `$\frac{a}{b}$`.

Comment: Hi! It's a nice question. However, from the perspective of math typography, such usage of this symbol is discouraged. It's preferable to always typeset the horizontal bar over the expression you make a root of: `\[ \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} \]`. Another solutions for your example are: `\[ \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} \]` (that's what I prefer) or `\[ \Bigl(\frac{a}{b}\Bigr)^{1/2} \]`.

Comment: @tohecz Thank you for your reply. While I prefer the same style '$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$' that you have suggested, my department is trying to adopt '$\surd$', which seems to be the standard notation for square root employed in Cambridge A-Level examinations. Thus, I am looking for ways to make the symbol '$\surd$' to match '$\sqrt$', minus the overline.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following definition:

```
\def\surdex#1{\sqrt{\vphantom{#1}}#1}
```

and the test:

```
$$\surdex{\frac{a}{b}}$$
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to have also the option of setting the root index; with `xparse` it's rather easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xroot}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\sqrt{\vphantom{#2}}#2}
    {\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{#2}}#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\xroot{\frac{1}{2}}\ne\xroot[3]{(a+b)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, seeing the result I ask myself why a respected institution wants to change a long time honored notation.

Comment: This is the _root_ of ugliness :-/ Especially the LHS.